# Import package directly from domain (e.g. goji)

Tags: go

I noticed while importing packages from goji - it is hosted directly off their domain e.g:

```
package web

import (
    "goji.io"
)

func Start() {
    mux := goji.NewMux()
}
```

How are the packages being requested by go and how is it hosted in this way? I can't find any documentation, so I'm thinking it might be a neat trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's documented in the `go` command, under [Remote Import Paths](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths).

> If the import path is not a known code hosting site and also lacks a
>   version control qualifier, the go tool attempts to fetch the import
>   over https/http and looks for a  tag in the document's HTML
>   .
>
> The meta tag has the form:
>
> ```
> <meta name="go-import" content="import-prefix vcs repo-root">
> ```
>
> The import-prefix is the import path corresponding to the repository root.
>   It must be a prefix or an exact match of the package being fetched
>   with "go get". If it's not an exact match, another http request is
>   made at the prefix to verify the  tags match.

Comment: Thanks! I see from goji.io:
`<meta name="go-import" content="goji.io git https://github.com/goji/goji">
    <meta name="go-source" content="goji.io https://github.com/goji/goji/ https://github.com/goji/goji/tree/master{/dir} https://github.com/goji/goji/blob/master{/dir}/{file}#L{line}">`